# How to get svg and mouse cursor position correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm trying to make a vertical draggable thermometer type component. You hold on the circle thing with the arrows and drag up and down and it moves with the cursor. With normal HTML/JS this is easy but I can't seem to figure out how to get the svg piece to move with the mouse. Right now it moves in the right direction but it's way off from the cursor.

I've read about a dozen answers of this on Stackoverflow and they all seem to use the same code which i have at my link, but it's still off. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at all.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/qoyozej/3/edit?html,js,output

p.s. the `width` and `height` in the `<style>` tag works fine in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox. I'm not sure how to fix that yet so the color bars wont show up in Firefox right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `evt.clientX` and `evt.clientY`, which gives you the coordinates of the mouse event on the *page*.

You need to subtract the (top left) position of the SVG from the coords before you do the transform.

Answer (score 0):

apart from calculating the relative position of your element on the page (as paul's answer suggest), you also need to consider how viewbox affects your graphic;

- for calculating the correct position relative to page you can use getBoundingRect() method on the svg elem,
- for calculating the correct scaling you could do some math dividing height with viewbox height and multiply that by cursor.y (or you could use scale inside the transformation).